# document.getElementById throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, null, getelementbyid, typeerror

I am a bit new to Javascript. I am writing this dummy script to test out what I need for my larger page. I want, at the simplest, to get the value of href and then change the value of href and then see it again. TO keep it simple, right now I have removed the part for changing the href value and just calling the attribute value twice. But the second time I access the attribute value it show an error which I have posted below. I'm posting two error logs one from Firebug and one from Dragonfly(from Opera).

Any help would be dearly appreciated. Thanks.

One more issue I have with the script is that it never finishes loading. I always see (in Firefox 3.6.8) the little loading sign going round and round in the tab title. It doesn't bother me so much but if anyone has an idea please tell me.

```
<!-- This file is used to set attribute value for href. -->
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function hrefvalue()
{
var thisthang = document.getElementById("1").childNodes[0].getAttribute("href");
document.write(thisthang);
document.write("\n");

var newnew21 = document.getElementById("1").childNodes[0].getAttribute("href");
document.write(newnew21);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="1"><a href="focusdude.htm">click here</a></div>
<button type="button" onclick="hrefvalue()">Click me instead</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Error logs : 
1. Firebug -> document.getElementById("1") is null 

2. Dragonfly -> 
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById("1")' to object

Error thrown at line 8, column 0 in hrefvalue() in 
file://localhost/D:/Chicago%20pics/website%20pics/website%20root/trial5.htm: 
    var newnew21 = document.getElementById("1").childNodes[0].getAttribute("href"); 
called from line 1, column 0 in (event):
    hrefvalue() 

And thanks again for all the fish :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An id can't start with a number (in HTML 4). Don't bet on browsers supporting such ids.
2. `document.write` will trash a document that isn't *open*. When the browser parses `</html>` the document is closed. Since the function runs `onclick`, it will be closed before you try to write. Use [DOM methods](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/) to modify HTML with JS.

Comment: So why does the first one work ? <br></br> I get an output for document.write(thisthang), but not for newnew21.

Comment: Because you haven't destroyed the element you are trying to read *before* that *first* time you call `document.write`

Comment: *"An id can't start with a number"* FWIW, that *used* to be true [in HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), and it's still true [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), but [HTML5 now allows it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). Not that I'd use `1` as an `id`, mind. (The quoted page isn't specifying any doctype at all, but hey.)

Comment: I tried this fiddle and there is no problem with elements having only number(s) for their ids : http://jsfiddle.net/g3sfW/1/

Comment: @K.A.G.: Right, there isn't. The rules used to forbid it, and you still can't do it with CSS selectors, but the rules have been loosened (partially to reflect the reality that browsers didn't care).

Comment: @K.A.G / @T.J. Crowder  — I wouldn't bet on all browsers having caught up though.

Comment: Ohh.. got it.. Thanks... would've taken me atleast an hour to figure it out on my own. The loading problem is solved too .. I changed the code to this : 
    var thisthang = document.getElementById("idthis").childNodes[0].getAttribute("href");
    alert(thisthang);

    var newnew21 = document.getElementById("idthis").childNodes[0].getAttribute("href");
    alert(newnew21);

Comment: @Quentin: It's the other way around, I'm pretty sure the spec is capturing the reality on the ground in this case.